# how can i change the image in button inside in datatemplate wpf

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, datatemplate

how i say in title, i have a datatemplate for a Telerik RadTileView, in the large content i have a toolbar with a play button, the idea is that when a user click this button, the images in the tile view change automatically, i already do that but i need change the image inside the play button with a stop icon, this is my data template:

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="contentTemplate">
            <telerik:RadFluidContentControl>
                <telerik:RadFluidContentControl.Content>
                    <Border>
                        <Image Source="{Binding Frame}" />
                    </Border>
                </telerik:RadFluidContentControl.Content>
                <telerik:RadFluidContentControl.LargeContent>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid>
                            <Image Source="{Binding Frame}" />
                        </Grid>
                        <Border BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="1" Background="#80000000" Height="80" VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource BotonGrande}" Name="BotonImagenAtras" Click="BotonImagenAtras_Click">
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImagenGrande}" Source="/VisorSeproban;component/Imagenes/izquierda.png" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource BotonGrande}" Name="BotonImagenesPlay" Click="BotonImagenesPlay_Click">
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImagenGrande}" Source="/VisorSeproban;component/Imagenes/play_on.png" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource BotonGrande}" Name="BotonCaputarImagen" Click="BotonCaputarImagen_Click">
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImagenGrande}" Source="/VisorSeproban;component/Imagenes/captura_img_on.png" />
                                </Button>
                                <Button Style="{StaticResource BotonGrande}" Name="BotonImagenAdelante" Click="BotonImagenAdelante_Click">
                                    <Image Style="{StaticResource ImagenGrande}" Source="/VisorSeproban;component/Imagenes/derecha.png" />
                                </Button>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </telerik:RadFluidContentControl.LargeContent>
            </telerik:RadFluidContentControl>
        </DataTemplate>
```

Thanks for your help!
Regards

Answer (score 0):

try attaching an event an change the image when the event get fire. you can try with Javascript if you are running your app in a browser.